# Converting to JSON String with JsonUtility.ToJson

Tags: unity, c#, serialization, json

I am working on converting and displaying the JSON String with unity. I have done coding for it

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using LitJson;
using SimpleJSON;
using System.IO;
public class TestDelete : MonoBehaviour {


JsonData json;
void Start()
{
    Data2 data = new Data2();
    Payload2 data2 = new Payload2();
    data.command = "state";
    data.payload = new Payload2()
    {
        text = "wwwwwww", 
        image = "hello" 

    };
    data2.option = new Option () {
        A1 = "k",
        A2 = "J"

    };

    string dataValue =data+ data2.ToString();
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(data,true);
    P(json + "\t\n");

}

// Use this for initialization
void P(string aText)
{
    print (aText +"\n");
}

}

  [System.Serializable]
  public class Payload2
   {
     public string text;
     public string image;
      public Option option;


    }

  [System.Serializable]
   public class Data2
   {
     public string command;
     public Payload2 payload;
   }

   [System.Serializable]
   public class Option
    {
      public string A1;
      public string A2;
    }
```

This code of working fine.But with the output Iam having problem.The out is displayed as follow

```
{
"command": "state",
"payload": {
    "text": "wwwwwww",
    "image": "hello",
    "option": {
        "A1": "", // not getting displayed
        "A2": ""   // not getting displayed
    }
}
```

}

the string value A1 and A2 is not getting displayed.What will be the issue with my code.Can anybody help me sorting out this issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings are on initial value because you never set `data.payload.option` to anything.

You set up a variable `Payload2 data2`, but you never assign it in any way to anything of the variable `data`.

Try replacing `data2.option = new Option () {` with `data.payload.option = new Option () {`

By the way: I have no idea what the line `string dataValue =data+ data2.ToString();`
 is supposed to do, because the variable `dataValue` isn't used anywhere.

Comment: Will I be able to display only some part of the json string.for example : under "option" can I able to display only A1.

Comment: @user1509674 This appears to be a new question.